# ASPxGridview Change Default value in inline EditForm

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I'm trying to change the value in an editform before it becomes visible to the user. However the aspxgridview is always overwriting this.

This is my solution:

```
 Protected Sub ASPxGridView_ItemList_HtmlRowCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.ASPxGridViewTableRowEventArgs) Handles ASPxGridView_Items.HtmlRowCreated
        If (e.RowType = GridViewRowType.EditForm) Then
            Dim ASPxTextbox_Number As ASPxTextBox = TryCast(TryCast(sender, ASPxGridView).FindEditFormTemplateControl("ASPxTextbox_Number"), ASPxTextBox)
            ASPxTextbox_Number.Text = "99"
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the [How to update an ASPxGridView DataSource if the initial values are set programmatically in the HtmlRowCreated event](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/CodeCentral/ViewExample.aspx?exampleId=E457) example in this regard.